# what will be the solution with asp.net core 3.1 web api

Tags: asp.net-core

I am implementing jwt security using asp.net web api app along with owin like below,

```
 using Microsoft.Owin;
 using Owin;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
 using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;

 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(solution.Startup))]

  namespace solution 
 {
 public class Startup
 {
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.MapSignalR();
  HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  ConfigureOAuth(app);
  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
  app.UseWebApi(config);
}
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
  var issuer = "issuer";
  var audience = "audience";
  var secret = JwtSecurityKey.Create("SecurityKey").GetSymmetricKey();

  // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
  var option =
      new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
      {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
          {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
          }
      };
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        option
    );
 }
}
  }
```

Any guideline or tutorial how to convert this to asp.net core web api application?

Comment: You can check the tutorial : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the startup file you could do something similar to this:

ConfigureServices method

```
            // Configure JWT authentication
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AppConfig.Secret);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,      //or true
                    ValidateAudience = false,    //or true
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    //ValidIssuer = "somewhere.com",
                    //ValidAudience = "somewhere.com",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
                };
            });
```

...and in the Configure method

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
```